# Eclipse RCP Application with Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an application based on eclipse RCP and would like to use maven to resolve dependecies of libraries, like: hibernate, jpa, htmlunit, and so on.

The problem is that the eclipse RCP environment does not recognize the dependencies resolved by maven.

I read the tycho tutorial, but everything was done in command line, outside de eclipse environment and I can't debug the application because the eclipse environment does note recogneze de dependecies. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method for you would be to add the dependencies in your Manifest.mf

After you need to -

- Goto Eclipse Marketplace. Install Maven Integration For Eclipse

[image]

- Install Tycho connector for M2Eclipse.

For this Goto Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Discovery -> Open Catalog ....

[image]

And now configure the pom.xml to use Tycho to do your builds. This way eclipse will be able to resolve your dependencies.

Comment: Additionally, the [Tycho user mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/tycho-user) is a great source for any help you might need with regards to Tycho. Also, check out the target platform section in [this blog post](http://blog.sdruskat.net/building-a-cross-platform-feature-based-eclipse-rcp-product-with-tycho-the-umpteenth/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but you can't use maven like that (like on a web app) on RCP apps...You'll need a p2 repo with all your dependencies, a `target` file and tycho will read these deps, compile and gerenater your final product.

Answer (score 0):

You will want https://tycho.eclipseprojects.io/doc/latest/ which is a plugin for Maven that enables target platform resolution. With https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/ you can then in return add maven artifacts into the target platform.

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding the steps to take to use and configure those plugins and explain how that makes the eclipse RCP environment recognize maven dependencies.